# Django for loop in html template not displaying

Tags: python, html, django

So I am trying to get the latest post and I ran into a problem where it will not display the post

views.py

```
def latest_post(request):
    latest = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
    context = {'latestPost': latest}
    return render(request, 'latest_post.html', context)
```

Note: I also tried it with this, latest = Post.objects.all()

There are entries in the database, I tested with the shell

```
from blog.models import Post
>>> Post.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Post: test>, <Post: okay so>, <Post: okay-okay>]>
```

latest_post.html

```
{% for newest in latestPost %}
<section class="hero is-primary is-medium">
  <div class="hero-body header">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="font">
      <h1 class="title is-1">
        <span id="blog_title">{{ newest.title }}</span>
      </h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle is-3 subup">
        <span id="blog-subtitle">{{ newest.content|truncatechars:20|safe }}</span>
      </h2>
      <h2 class="subtitle is-5 dateup">
        <span id="blogdate">{{ newest.timestamp }}</span><br><br>
        <a href="{{ newest.blog_url }}" class="button is-danger is-large is-inverted">Read More >></a>
      </h2>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
{% endfor %}
```

in my blog_index.html I have the following

```
{% extends "blog_base.html" %}
{% block blog_main %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% include 'latest_post.html' %}
<p> other html here </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Latest_post.html displays when i use {% include 'latest_post.html' %} only if I don't use

```
{% for newest in latestPost %}
{% endfor %}
```

So i am sure there aren't any typos somewhere that prevents the latest_post.html from displaying in my index page.

my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title

    def blog_url(self):
        return reverse("blogposts:blogdetail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Additional Notes: python3, django 1.11, sqlite.
Also, No errors are displayed in the console. any help would be appreciated! thank you!!

Comment: Do you only want the latest post? If so, you don't need to use a for loop in the first place

Comment: it returns the html without the loop, but doing {{ latestPost.title }} etc... does not display the content in the views. am I missing something ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are passing context variable to `latest_post.html` directly:

```
return render(request, 'latest_post.html', context)
```

But there is no such context variable `latestPost` in `blog_index.html`.
What you need to do is add context to `blog_index.html`. Add this to `index` view also:

```
latest = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
context = {'latestPost': latest}
return render(request, 'blog_index.html', context)
```

Also you can use [first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#first) to select first element in queryset.

Comment: I unfortunately think this is not the problem, I might be missing something somewhere. I have tried your suggestion, but it still returns the html with missing database items!!! it's extremely frustrating because I know the problem is something small, I appreciate the tip on the first() last() though! did not know that.

Comment: try rerun `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate`. Please backup your database before attempting in case @Fanna1119

Comment: My problem was I did something wrong in a model that did not read the model if it was not "published" , however your answer was also part of the solution, rendering to the blog_index.html instead of latest_post.html which makes a lot of sense actually, it renders the index and gathers via {% include %} Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your previous code you are limiting it by using `[:1]` so it only returns one item. Then you are using a forloop again on one item. Not the best way to do things.

> Are you trying to get only one item from the post? If yes, Forloop is not needed change your `latest_post.html` to

```
<section class="hero is-primary is-medium">
  <div class="hero-body header">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="font">
      <h1 class="title is-1">
        <span id="blog_title">{{ latestPost.title }}</span>
      </h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle is-3 subup">
        <span id="blog-subtitle">{{ latestPost.content|truncatechars:20|safe }}</span>
      </h2>
      <h2 class="subtitle is-5 dateup">
        <span id="blogdate">{{ latestPost.timestamp }}</span><br><br>
        <a href="{{ latestPost.blog_url }}" class="button is-danger is-large is-inverted">Read More >></a>
      </h2>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

You don't even need to use the `[:1]` in your views. There are better ways to do this

Comment: I tried it like this but strangely enough it still does not return anything??with and without the for loop, I am so confused at the moment. it does return the html but the content & title and everything is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck in the same problem and I was damn confirmed that I was doing any silly mistakes.

Unfortunately, I found one. So,
Try this:

```
context = {'latest': latest}
```

Instead of:

```
context = {'latestPost': latest}
```

I hope it works.